# how to output/bundle/compile/whatever some js libraries into a single file with gulp?

Tags: vue.js, npm, gulp, package.json

I am a .net developer who recently came to web dev (vue.js). As far as I can see, the web development today is totally alien to me. require, export, npm, gulp, node js... here is my situation right now:

so I have created a .net 5 web project,and decided to use vue.js as the main framework. I saw there are 4 differently ways of installation (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html). The only one I feel comfortable with is to just add a  tag with src pointed to the vue.js I downloaded to my project folder. So far so good, my very first vue app is up and running.
Now I need a datepicker component, so I've found this: https://github.com/icehaunter/vue3-datepicker  Now comes the tricky part:

I downloaded the zip package from github, and can not find a single js file I can just put to my webpage with a  tag. In fact there is even NOT a vue3-datepicker.js on the entire web!

I know my knowledge of web development is centuries old, so I learnt to use npm, with a package.json in my project as following:

```
    {
  "name": "my.fancy.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "3.0.11",
    "vue3-datepicker": "0.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

and also installed gulp.

But now what? How am I suppose to get those libraries/dependencies as  tag in my html?

I know that gulp will do the magic, but it is just too tricky for me to figure it out. Can any only point me to the right direction?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: *The only one I feel comfortable with is to just add a tag with src pointed to the vue.js I downloaded to my project folder* - then you drew a short straw. You can use Vue like that in theory, but in practice the ecosystem heavily relies on its own .vue format and Webpack, so Gulp alone isn't enough for real world project. Use Vue CLI for a ready-to-use setup.

Comment: so right now, my only need is to just be able to load the vue.js and datepicker.js to page, so I can continue to right some vanilla js, yeah but thanks for the informaiton, I guess it will take me a wake or so to get comfortable with those new things.

Comment: You can use datepicker.js, but as long as you try to use something from Vue ecosystem, you will find out that most libs aren't supposed to be used with vanilla JS, only few major ones (Vuex, router). They don't provide a prebuilt JS bundle that could be loaded in a browser as is. This includes vue3-datepicker.

Comment: figured out that all I need is browserify.